# AJAX call on same page $_POST variable is empty

Tags: php, html, ajax, post

I just readed a lot of topics about this, but still i can't make it work. Uploaded it to a live server and tried on localhost with XAMPP, still the same happens.

On developer tools/firebug i can see the result, the same happens on network/ XHR. Any help is appreciated.

I want to compare a radio button submit value with a php variable (As seen in index.php) On console it works as expected but not on my browser window.

**html.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>

          <form name="curso_activo" id="form_preguntas" method="POST" action="" >
              <p> option1 </p>
              <input id="input_1" type="radio" name="html1" value="a">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>


              <p> option2 </p>
              <input id="input_2" type="radio" name="html1" value="b">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>


              <p> option3 </p>
              <input id="input_3" type="radio" name="html1" value="c">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>


              <p> option4 </p>
              <input id="input_4" type="radio" name="html1" value="d">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>


            <div class="respuesta_submit">
            <input type="submit"  id="Respuesta_send" class="button_submit"  value="Enviar" name="Enviar_respuesta">
            </div>

          </form>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"> </script>
  <script src="ajax.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**ajax.js**

```
$("#form_preguntas").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var question = $("#input_1").attr('name');
    var answer = $("input[name=" + question + "]:checked").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'param': answer},
        success: function (data,) {
            console.log(data);
            alert(question);

        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
});
```

**index.php**

```
    <?php  
require"html.php";

$correct_answer = 'b';

if ($_POST['param'] == $correct_answer) {
    echo "Correct";
}

?>
```

Comment: Doesn't it just work as expected? AJAX doesn't refresh the page, it just sends and receives data in the background, without reloading the page (unless you tell JavaScript to). So in your console you see the AJAX response, but in your browser window you keep seeing the page as if the form is not submitted.

Comment: @DecentDabbler Yes you're right, but if i want to acomplish this
if (isset($_POST['param'])) {
    echo "PRINT THIS";
}
i can't do it on the same page? only works in console

Comment: Yes, but you have now edited your question. Originally you wanted to show "POST PARAM IS SET", which it does in your original picture (in the console part, on the right). :) I just think you misunderstand how AJAX works. If you want, I can explain in an answer.

Comment: Yes, you can do that: either don't use AJAX, but simply post the form as normal (which will refresh the page), or DO use AJAX but replace the original HTML of the initial page with JavaScript when AJAX returns a response (which is a bit broad to explain, perhaps). You can search StackOverflow about how you can replace HTML with JavaScript/AJAX. There's lots of examples already.

Comment: @DecentDabbler I edited the post again, i think the example is more clear now. I want to compare the  value of a radio button submited value with a php variable. 
This is just an example, the right answer is actually from a database, that's why i need to do it with PHP that way. Hope i'm explaining myself better. 
Also thanks for your response

Comment: @Andrew i want the user to see if the answer submited is the same as the variable stored on index.php. actually it only works on console

Comment: Your question is very clear Dani_lotup, it's just that you misunderstand how AJAX works. Please carefully try to reread what I have commented so far and ask yourself if you've fully understood what I am trying to say. If not, I'll write you an answer later on (gonna have dinner first :) ).

Comment: @Decent Dabbler Thank you for the answers, you made me think again how Ajax works. managed to make it work now. Will answer my own question later on

Comment: @Dani_lotup That's great to hear. Yes, definitely answer your own question if you've come up with your own solution. And I'd love to see what you have come up with, as well.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution in your javascript, check if the response is what you expected, then tell the user:

```
...

success: function (data,) {
  if (data == 'success'){
     //do something here
     $('#someDiv').html('success!');
  }
},

...
```